# how to display anchor in ng-grid column?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Trying to create a ng-grid with a link ie anchor in the first column. It is supposed to redirect to another page ie person passing in the Id for the person:

```
<a href="/person/{{row.getProperty(col.field)}">{{row.getProperty(name)}</a>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePinning: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            field: 'id',
            displayName: 'PersonLink',
            enableCellEdit: false,
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a href="/person/{{row.getProperty(col.field)}">{{row.getProperty(name)}</a></div>'
        },
        { field: "name", width: 120, pinned: true },
        { field: "age", width: 120 },
        { field: "birthday", width: 120 },
        { field: "salary", width: 120 }

    ]
};

$scope.myData = [
    { id:1,name: "Moroni", age: 50, birthday: "Oct 28, 1970", salary: "60,000" },
    { id:2,name: "Tiancum", age: 43, birthday: "Feb 12, 1985", salary: "70,000" },
    { id:3,name: "Jacob", age: 27, birthday: "Aug 23, 1983", salary: "50,000" },
    { id:4,name: "Nephi", age: 29, birthday: "May 31, 2010", salary: "40,000" },
    { id:5,name: "Enos", age: 34, birthday: "Aug 3, 2008", salary: "30,000" }

];
});
```

The link is not even displaying, can someone help out? thanks
Here is the plnkrlink:http://plnkr.co/edit/Yg1fVjVviZPQgwlpVNPb?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to fix your fiddle. The updated fiddle is here

http://plnkr.co/edit/hbN32G9KDU0vjR36tKgh?p=preview

The thing that needed fix were you were missing ending `}`

`{{row.getProperty(col.field)}`

Also pinned:true is not working maybe because you are doing it on second column. I moved it to first and it works.

Also the expression which refers a string should be fixed here

`{{row.getProperty(\'name\')}}`